# Apache proxy configuration in which a subpath is a proxy for a different port

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I wish to have the following happen:

- http://www.example.com/wiki be a proxy for http://www.example.com:8090/
- http://www.example.com/ be a proxy for http://www.example.com:8080/

I have the following Apache configuration. However, this has both http://www.example.com/ and http://www.example.com/wiki be a proxy for http://www.example.com:8080/. How can I correct this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy /wiki>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass        /wiki http://www.example.com:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse /wiki http://www.example.com:8090/

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass        /     http://www.example.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /     http://www.example.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If the first argument of ProxyPass ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing / and vice versa. Otherwise the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.

Comment: Any reason not to use name-based virtual hosting?

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I had my Tomcat server.xml file for the site hosted on 8090 set to

```
<Context path="/wiki"
```

Thus, I needed to have

```
    ProxyPass        /wiki http://www.example.com:8090/wiki
    ProxyPassReverse /wiki http://www.example.com:8090/wiki
```

in the Apache configuration.